# MYSQL Sintax Error in the sentence with the attribute default

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello stackoverflows friends.

My problem in sql is this sintaxis:

```
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY COLUMN (role INT(10)) DEFAULT 2 NOT NULL;
```

I want to modify a column in this case role but my default should be 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax should work:

```
alter table user modify column role int default 2;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8d57a) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - For SQL

```
 ALTER TABLE USER ALTER COLUMN ROLE SET DEFAULT(2);
```

For MySql :

```
ALTER TABLE USER ALTER ROLE SET DEFAULT(2);
```